# 3D Geometry: Finding viewing boundaries from camera postion, min and max length of view, angle it is pointing and angle of view

Tags: c++, 3d, geometry

I am writing software to determine the viewable locations of a camera in 3D. I have currently implement parts to find the minimum and maximum length of view based on the camera and lenses intrinsic characteristics.

I now need to work out that if the camera is placed at X,Y,Z and is pointing in a direction (two angles, one around the horizontal and one around the vertical axis) what the boundaries the camera can see at are (knowing the viewing angle). The output I would like is 4 3D locations, making a rectangle that show the minimum position, top left, top right, bottom left and bottom right. The same is also required for the maximum positions.

Can anyone help with the geometry to find these points?

Some code I have:

```
QVector3D CameraPerspective::GetUnitVectorOfCameraAngle()
{
  QVector3D inital(0, 1, 0);
  QMatrix4x4 rotation_matrix;

  // rotate around z axis
  rotation_matrix.rotate(_angle_around_z, 0, 0, 1);

  //rotate around y axis
  rotation_matrix.rotate(_angle_around_x, 1, 0, 0);

  inital = inital * rotation_matrix;

  return inital;
}

Coordinate CameraPerspective::GetFurthestPointInFront()
{
  QVector3D camera_angle_vector = GetUnitVectorOfCameraAngle();
  camera_angle_vector.normalize();
  QVector3D furthest_point_infront = camera_angle_vector * _camera_information._maximum_distance_mm;

  return Coordinate(furthest_point_infront + _position_of_this);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you define viewing angle? Is it the angle from the center of the visual field to an edge, or from an edge to the opposite edge?

Comment: The full viewing angle of the camera i.e from one edge to another. Both horizontally and vertically.

Answer (score 0):

A complete answer with code will be probably way too long for SO, I hope that this will be enough. In the following we work in [homogeneous coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates).

> I have currently implement parts to find the minimum and maximum length of view based on the camera and lenses intrinsic characteristics.

That isn't enough to fully define your camera. You also need a field of view angle and the width/height ratio.

With all these information (near plane + far plane + fov + ratio), you can build a 4x4 matrix known as *perspective matrix*. Google for it or check [here](http://www.geeks3d.com/20090729/howto-perspective-projection-matrix-in-opengl/) for some references. This matrix maps the pyramidal region of the space which your camera "sees" (usually simply called *frustrum*) to the [-1,1]x[-1,1]x[-1,1] cube. Call it **P**.

Now you need a 4x4 *camera matrix* which transform points in world space to points in camera space. Since you know the camera position and the camera orientation this can be constructed easily (there is no room here to full explain how transformation matrices in homogeneous coordinates work, google for it). Call this matrix **C**.

Now consider the matrix **A** = **P** * **C**.

This matrix transforms points in world coordinates to points in the perspective space. Your camera will "see" those points if they are inside the [-1,1]x[-1,1]x[-1,1] cube. But you can invert this matrix in order to map points inside the cube to points in world space. So in order to obtain the 8 points you need in world space you can simply do:

**y** = **A**^(-1) * **x**

Where **x** =

- [-1,-1,-1, 1] left - bottom - near
- [-1,-1, 1, 1] left - bottom - far
- etc.